# Bulk Excel data import with nested relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, bulkinsert, excel-import

I am getting slow performance issue in excel data import with nested relationships.

I have two main tables to insert and other four tables which have one-to-many and many-to-many relationships with main tables.

I check imported data for four tables are existing or new before data is inserted for two main tables as imported file may have same data for four tables and same data cannot insert multiple times.

That's why performance is slow.

How could I solve this issue?

Comment: can you show how slow?

Answer (score 0):

I have had to deal with this situation with bulk data that includes million of records. From many wasted weeks of experience:

1) Do everything in your power not to use excel. It is slow and eats up loads of memory. A single sheet with 500,00 records can end up eating up over 2 gigabytes of memory just to load the file. The imports then take 30-40-50 minutes or more for a single sheet. Consider converting the data to CSV and importing it using `SqlBulkCopy`. It can handle a massive amount of records on the order of seconds to a few minutes as opposed to hours.

2) There's not much you can do when it comes to improving the performance o Entity Framework in this situation. I found the best and fastest approach was to load each sheet into its own temp table in the Database. Then I constructed SQL to do the bulk inserts into their end tables. Results of intermediate inserts can be captured into output tables so you can access the keys necessary to perform any joins from the temp table or inserts into related tables.  You can of course "steal` some of the auto generated EF SQL but then you'll need to fine tune it.

3) Even though SQL hates loops, I coded my sql statements to run in a loop and inserts of say 100,000 records at a time. It made the inserts run much faster.

To give you an idea, after bulk importing each sheet form CSV:

First define your variables and types stored in related tables as needed:

```
DECLARE @Max INT = @RecordsPerLoop
DECLARE @Min INT = 0
DECLARE @TotalRECORD INT = (
        SELECT count(*)
        FROM TempClassMemberRecords
        )
DECLARE @Country VARCHAR(50)

SET @Country = 'USA'

-- Const variables for class member inserts
DECLARE @DefaultCommPreference VARCHAR(50) = (
        SELECT TOP 1 CommPreference
        FROM Actors
        WHERE PKID = 0
        )
    ,@PrimaryActorTypeId INT = (
        SELECT TOP 1 PKId
        FROM ActorTypes
        WHERE ActorTypeName = 'PrimaryClaimant'
        )
    ,@SecondaryActorTypeId INT = (
        SELECT TOP 1 PKId
        FROM ActorTypes
        WHERE ActorTypeName = 'CoClaimant'
        )
    ,@HomePhoneTypeId INT = (
        SELECT TOP 1 PKId
        FROM PhoneTypes
        WHERE PhoneTypeName = 'Home'
        )
    ,@WorkPhoneTypeId INT = (
        SELECT TOP 1 PKId
        FROM PhoneTypes
        WHERE PhoneTypeName = 'Work'
        )
    ,@PrimaryCountryId INT = IsNull((
            SELECT TOP 1 PKId
            FROM Countries
            WHERE @Country IN (
                    CountryName
                    ,CountryCode
                    )
            ), 0)
    ,@DefaultCountryId INT = IsNull((
            SELECT TOP 1 PKId
            FROM Countries
            WHERE CountryCode = 'USA'
            ), 0)
    ,@SubmitTypeId INT = (
        SELECT TOP 1 PKId
        FROM ClaimSubmitTypes
        WHERE SubmitTypeName = 'Bulk'
        )
    ,@ClaimStatusId INT = (
        SELECT TOP 1 PKId
        FROM ClaimStatusTypes
        WHERE StatusName = 'Active'
        )
    ,@ModifiedBy VARCHAR(20) = @uploadUser
    ,@ModifiedDate DATETIME = GETDATE()
    ,@CaseCode VARCHAR(50) = (
        SELECT TOP 1 CaseCode
        FROM Cases
        ORDER BY PKId DESC
        ) + ''
    ,@IndividualClaimantType INT = (
        SELECT TOP 1 PKId
        FROM claimanttypes
        WHERE ClaimantTypeName = 'Individual'
        )
    ,@CompanyClaimantType INT = (
        SELECT TOP 1 PKId
        FROM claimanttypes
        WHERE ClaimantTypeName = 'Corporation'
        )
    ,@Checked BIT = 0
    ,@startingPKId INT = (
        SELECT max(PKId) + 1
        FROM dbo.Entities WITH (NOLOCK)
        );

--Record per group insert
IF (@TotalRECORD <= @RecordsPerLoop)
    SET @max = @TotalRECORD
```

The run your insert loop:

```
-- our main loop
WHILE (@min <= @TotalRECORD)
BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#EntityIds') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #EntityIds

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RefNumRepository') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #RefNumRepository

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ActorIds') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #ActorIds

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SecondaryActorIds') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #SecondaryActorIds

    CREATE TABLE #EntityIds (
        pkid INT identity(1, 1) NOT NULL
        ,mid INT
        ,eid INT
        )

    CREATE TABLE #ActorIds (
        pkid INT identity(1, 1) NOT NULL
        ,mid INT
        ,aid INT
        )

    CREATE TABLE #SecondaryActorIds (
        pkid INT identity(1, 1) NOT NULL
        ,mid INT
        ,aid INT
        )

    CREATE TABLE #RefNumRepository (
        pkid INT identity(1, 1) NOT NULL
        ,RefNum VARCHAR(50)
        )

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    BEGIN TRY
        UPDATE TOP (@RecordsPerLoop + 1) RefNumRepository
        SET IsUsed = 1
        OUTPUT deleted.RefNum
        INTO #RefNumRepository(RefNum)
        WHERE IsUsed = 0;

        PRINT 'Entities'
        INSERT INTO Entities (
            ModifiedBy
            ,ModifiedDate
            ,RecordOwnerName
            ,IsConflictOfInterest
            ,FKClaimantTypeId
            ,OtherClaimantType
            ,InstitutionAccountNumber
            ,RefNum
            ,FKSubmitTypeId
            ,FKClaimStatusTypeId
            ,RecordType
            ,ClaimNum
            ,FilingDate
            ,FirstName
            ,Lastname
            ,Email
            ,SSN
            ,Source
            ,ClaimDataCertifiedDate
            )
        OUTPUT Inserted.pkid
            ,Inserted.source
        INTO #EntityIds(eid, mid)
        SELECT @ModifiedBy
            ,@ModifiedDate
            ,NULL
            ,1
            ,CASE 
                WHEN IsNull(company, '') = ''
                    THEN @IndividualClaimantType
                ELSE @CompanyClaimantType
                END
            ,NULL
            ,NULL
            ,''
            ,@SubmitTypeId
            ,@ClaimStatusId
            ,'CM'
            ,NULL
            ,@ModifiedDate
            ,IsNull(fname, '')
            ,IsNull(lname, '')
            ,IsNull(Email, '')
            ,IsNull(ssn, '')
            ,rawID
            ,@ModifiedDate
        FROM TempClassMemberRecords
        WHERE rawID BETWEEN @min
                AND @max
            AND IsProcessed IS NULL

        EXEC dbo.[USP_AssignClassMemberRefNums] @startingPKId

        PRINT 'Actors'
        -- bulk insert our range of class members into Actors while inserting the primary key into our temp table
        INSERT INTO Actors (
            FKActorTypeId
            ,ModifiedBy
            ,ModifiedDate
            ,LastName
            ,FirstName
            ,MiddleName
            ,CommPreference
            ,IsPayee
            ,IsUSCitizen
            ,ein
            ,ssn
            ,company
            ,attention
            ,NotificationsBlocked
            ,SearchName
            ,ClientAcctNumber
            )
        OUTPUT Inserted.pkid
            ,inserted.attention
        INTO #ActorIds(aid, mid)
        SELECT @PrimaryActorTypeId
            ,@ModifiedBy
            ,@ModifiedDate
            ,IsNull(lname, '')
            ,IsNull(fname, '')
            ,''
            ,IsNull(@DefaultCommPreference, 'Mail')
            ,1
            ,NULL
            ,IsNull(ein, '')
            ,IsNull(ssn, '')
            ,IsNull(company, '')
            ,rawid
            ,0
            ,CASE WHEN len(ISNULL(company, '')) > 0 THEN company  
            ELSE 
            CASE WHEN (len(ISNULL(lname, '')) > 0 OR len(ISNULL(fname, '')) > 0)
            THEN lname + ', ' +  fname   
            ELSE ''
            END
            END
            ,ACCTNUM
        FROM TempClassMemberRecords
        WHERE (
                isnull(company, '') <> ''
                OR isNull(fname, '') <> ''
                OR isNull(lname, '') <> ''
                )
            AND rawid BETWEEN @Min
                AND @Max
            AND IsProcessed IS NULL


    PRINT 'Entities2Actors'
    -- bulk insert the relations of Entities to Actors in Entities2Actors
    INSERT INTO Entities2Actors (
        FKEntityId
        ,FKActorId
        ,IsActorBeneficiary
        ,ModifiedBy
        ,ModifiedDate
        )
    SELECT e.eid
        ,a.aid
        ,1
        ,@ModifiedBy
        ,@ModifiedDate
    FROM #EntityIds e
    INNER JOIN #ActorIds a ON e.mid = a.mid
    -- etc...
    PRINT 'Addressed'
    --Bulk Insert into Address table for Primary Actor Address
    INSERT INTO Addresses (
        FKActorId
        ,ModifiedBy
        ,ModifiedDate
        ,Address1
        ,Address2
        ,City
        ,STATE
        ,Zip
        ,Zip4
        ,FKCountryId
        )
    SELECT a.aid
        ,@ModifiedBy
        ,@ModifiedDate
        ,IsNull(Address, '')
        ,IsNull(Address2, '')
        ,IsNull(City, '')
        ,IsNull([State], '')
        ,IsNull(Zip, '')
        ,IsNull(Zip4, '')
        ,ISNULL(@PrimaryCountryId, @DefaultCountryId)
    FROM #ActorIds a
    INNER JOIN TempClassMemberRecords c ON a.mid = c.rawId
-- etc...
UPDATE tempClassMemberRecords
    SET IsProcessed = 1
    WHERE rawid BETWEEN @Min
            AND @Max
        AND IsProcessed IS NULL

    SET @Min = @max + 1
    SET @max = @max + @RecordsPerloop

    COMMIT TRANSACTION

    WAITFOR DELAY '000:00:00.400'
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

    RAISERROR (N'Error in moving data from Temporary table to Main tables.', -- Message text.
       1,
       1);

    PRINT 'Failed with error: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH
```

Comment: Thanks @Higgins
I'll try it later as busy now
For me, maximum records will be not more than 5000.

Answer (score 0):

Read the entire file into a string array object using the .Net ReadAllLines() method, then run a Parallel For loop to process all the lines in parallel.

```
private bool ProcessFile(string FolderPath, string FileExtension)
{
    try
    {
        //all files with requisite file extension
        DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(FolderPath);
        FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles(FileExtension);
        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
        {
            List<String> AllLines = new List<String>();
            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(file.FullName))
            {
                int x = 0;
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    AllLines.Add(sr.ReadLine());
                    x += 1;
                }
                sr.Close();
            } 

            Parallel.For(0, AllLines.Count, x =>
            { 
                InsertDataCheck(AllLines[x]);
            }); 

        }
        GC.Collect();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    return false;
}

private void InsertDataCheck(string Line)
{
   //check if you want to insert data on the basis of your condition
   //and then insert your data    
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ajay
I'll try it later as I'm busy now.